# Multiple popover for one button

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, click, popover

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create some popover. 
Is it possible to match e.g. two popovers to one single button and to call both at the same time by clicking on the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> two popovers to one single button

seems difficult.but,

> call both at the same time by clicking on the button

will be ok.

try

- surround the button by a element or put a "blank" element next to the button.
- then call the element popover on the same button.

Code like

```
<span id="popover1Span"><button type="button" class="btn" id="myButton">Double</button></span>
<span id="popover2Span">&nbsp;</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
            $(this).popover({
                title : "Popover 1",
                content : "Popover 1.",
                html : true,
                trigger : "manual",
                placement : "bottom"
            }).popover('toggle');
            $("#popover1Span").popover({
                title : "Popover 2",
                content : "Popover 2.",
                html : true,
                trigger : "manual",
                placement : "top"
            }).popover('toggle');
            $("#popover2Span").popover({
                title : "Popover 3",
                content : "Popover 3.",
                html : true,
                trigger : "manual",
                placement : "right"
            }).popover('toggle');
        });
    });
</script>
```